# How can I stop the infinite loop with a trigger?

Tags: python, triggers, infinite-loop

**I want the program to play sound until the user stops the program himself.**

My code:

```
import pathlib,time
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
from gtts import gTTS
```

```
english=["school", "book", "theater"]
select = str(input("press ENTER to Start Stop=>'s':"))
elements=('', 'p')
while True:  
    if select not in elements:
        print("Please Correct Selection--")
        continue
    elif select in elements:
        for pick in english:
            index = english.index(pick)
            eng = pick
            print(index, "-> ", eng)
            text_eng = eng
            my_eng_obj = gTTS(text=eng, lang="en", slow=False)
            text_eng = text_eng.replace(" ", "_")
            try:
                file_en = pathlib.Path(text_eng + ".mp3")
                if file_en.exists():
                    song_s = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_en)
                    play(song_s)
                    pass
                else:
                    my_eng_obj.save(text_eng + ".mp3")
                    song_s = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_en)
                    play(song_s)
            except:
                pass
            time.sleep(0.2)
```

The sound section is working properly. I need the infinite loop section.
How can I interrupt with an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****That's one of the solutions****

```
import time
from pynput import keyboard

print("Press Enter ==> Start\n"
      "Press p   ==> Exit")

check = ''
def Start(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        print("Started")
        return False
def Stop(key):
    global check
    if key==keyboard.KeyCode(char='p'):
        check = 'stop'
        return False
with keyboard.Listener(on_release=Start) as listener:
    listener.join()
    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_release=Stop)
    listener.start()
while True:
    print("Do Something:Test")
    time.sleep(1)
    if check == 'stop':
        print("\nLoop Stopped...!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
trigger = False


while True:  # infinite loop
    # Do something
    # Do something to make trigger True. Keep it false if you want to keep the loop running
    if 1 + 1 == 2:  # Example comparison
        trigger = True
    print("Hello World")
    if trigger:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```py
# Modify user message
select = str(input("press ENTER to Start Stop=>CTRL+C:"))

# Use a try/except within the while loop
while True:
    try:
        if select not in elements:
            # ...
        elif select in elements:
            # ...
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, @Laurent I tried that, but I couldn't get the result. I have a mac os maybe that's why.:/